# Highcharts tooltip is moving slowly with useof boost.js

Tags: highcharts

I have used Highcharts boost.js. Then in Line chart with multiple series tooltip is moving slowly.

This is my tooltip object

```
     tooltip: {
                shared:GraphDataObj.YAxisData.length > 1,
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 0,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                shadow: false,
                useHTML: true,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(247, 247, 247, 0)',
                formatter: function () {
                    var points = this.points;
                    var tooltipMarkup = "";
}}
```

Comment: Hi @Akhil kotha, I have tested your tooltip options and it seems to work correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ly0f1oz5/ Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Comment: I have used boost.js as i have multiple points and i have 8 axes  i am unable to reproduce that issue in fiddle

Comment: Please provide the code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see the problem more accurately.

Comment: @Akhil kotha - Without reproducing the problem we are unable to help you.